# Как работает технология Bonjour? Как реализовать подобное на C#?

Tags: c#, dns, apple

Установил AirServer на ПК для прослушивания музыки и удивился, что при подключении не нужно открывать порты или вводить на iPhone IP-адрес ПК на котором находится сервер. Узнал, что это реализуется с помощью технологии Bonjour и она это делает с помощью DNS. Как это реализуется? Ведь DNS сервер тоже имеет IP-адрес, и как его находит iPhone? Возможна ли реализация собственной технологии, подобной Bonjour, на C#?

Answer (score 0):

Общее название таких технологий - ZeroConf, реализация от Apple называется Bounjour, в Windows это реализовано через UPnP. Думаю, что реализация собственное подобной технологии - это мертворожденная идея, а вот использование UPnP/Bonjour - можешь попробовать.

Comment: Bonjour не особо хочется использовать, а UPnP будет так же работать и с apple устройствами?